# Access to get and set of two dimensions array

Tags: c++, get, set

I can access correctly my two dimensions array, and cange it..
look at my code.
i need to use `a.getcity` and hopefuly get `citytable[ ][ ]` that i can change it

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  bool checkcol_big(int fromA, int toB, int fromC,char city[][11]){
for (int i = fromA; i < toB; i++){
    if (city[fromC][i] == 'P'){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}


  bool checkrow_big(int fromA, int fromB, int fromC,char city[][11]){
for (int i = fromA; i <fromB; i++){
    if (city[i][fromC] == 'P'){
        return false;
    }
}
  return true;
 }

void changecity(char city[11][11], int  changerow, int changecol, int taxi)
  { 
       if (taxi == 1)
            city[changerow][changecol] = 'T1';
    else
          city[changerow][changecol] = 'T2';
  }


   Orgnizer::Orgnizer(const Taxi &taxi1, const Taxi &taxi2, City &a, Simulation &sim){
        if (sim.getOpp() == 1 || sim.getOpp() == 2)
   {
        if (sim.getFromcol() < sim.getTocol()){
        if (checkcol_big(sim.getFromcol(), sim.getTocol(), sim.getFromrow(), a.getCity)){
            if (sim.getFromrow() > sim.getTorow()){
                if (checkrow_big(sim.getFromrow(), sim.getTorow(), sim.getTocol(), a.getCity)){
                //a[sim.getTorow][sim.getTocol] == 'T1';
                    changecity(a.getCity, sim.getTorow(), sim.getTocol(), sim.getNumtaxi());

                //a[sim.getTorow][sim.getTocol] == 'T2';
              }
             }
            }
        }
  }
 }





  void City::setCity(char x[][11])

  citytable[11][11] = x[11][11];
 }

  char City::getCity() const
  {
return citytable[11][11];
  }
```

Comment: As you array size is `char x[11][11]` you can give value upto 10th index i.e `x[10][10]`.

Comment: my problem is that i don't know how to use a.getCity

Comment: Like `checkcol_big` function you can pass indexes return value of that index.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* City::getCity(int x, int y)
{
 return &citytable[x][y];
}
```

can work this way.

```
char * to_change = getCity(x,y);
*to_change = new_value;
```

Comment: i want to get all citytable to see if there are any 'P' to where i whant to move...
   if (checkcol_big(sim.getFromcol(), sim.getTocol(),        sim.getFromrow(), a.getCity(0, 0)))
i will get only on element no?

Comment: you can aceess citytable[x][y] by *(citytable + 11*x +y)

Comment: Can you show me how you use it and how it doesnot work? maybe I can get some clue

Comment: 'void Orgnizer::movepassenger(Orgnizer &org){

  if ((org.S1.getOpp() == 1) || (org.S1.getOpp() == 2))
       {
    if (org.S1.getFromcol() < org.S1.getTocol()){
     if (checkcol_big(org.S1.getFromcol(), org.S1.getTocol(), org.S1.getFromrow(), org.C1.getCity(citytable + 11 * x + y)))'


  'string *City::getCity(int x, int y)
  {
 return &citytable[x][y];
  }'